# Batch Script Only First If Statement Being Executed

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I have the following Batch Script

```
@echo off
cd %USERPROFILE%\desktop

IF EXIST output.txt (
   FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN (output.txt) DO (
     echo %%G
     IF "%%G" == "BUILD FAILED" (
       echo failed
       pause
       exit (1)
     )
     IF "%%G" == "BUILD SUCCESS" (
       echo success
       pause
       exit (0)
     )
  )
)
pause
```

It reads from a text file that has one line, either BUILD SUCCESS or BUILD FAILED. What I have determined is if the BUILD SUCCESS if statement is listed first and BUILD SUCCESS is in the file, it exits as expected. But, if BUILD SUCCESS is in the file and the BUILD SUCCESS if statement is second (like is shown in the code sample), it never captures it and makes it to the pause at the end of the file. My syntax highlighting is doing weird things with the parentheses so I assume it's something with how I am grouping things, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the parenthesis in the `exit` commands.

Answer (score 1):

This script works perfectly for me.  I hope it gives you the ideas you need to solve your issue:

```
@ECHO off
ECHO Start of script
IF NOT DEFINED T set T=Undefined Title
TITLE %T%
::cd %USERPROFILE%\desktop
IF NOT EXIST output.txt (
  ECHO Generating sample file...
  ECHO BUILD SUCCESS>output.txt
  ECHO BUILD FAILED>>output.txt
)

IF EXIST output.txt (
   FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN (output.txt) DO (
     echo %%G
     IF "%%G" == "BUILD FAILED" (
       echo failed
       GOTO :ERR
     )
     IF "%%G" == "BUILD SUCCESS" (
       echo success
     )
  )
)
GOTO :END
:ERR
ECHO Failed.  Will close in 10 seconds...
FOR /l %%a in (10,-1,1) do (TITLE %T% -- closing in %%as&ping -n 2 -w 1000 127.1>NUL)
EXIT 1
:END
ECHO End of script.  Will close in 10 seconds...
FOR /l %%a in (10,-1,1) do (TITLE %T% -- closing in %%as&ping -n 2 -w 1000 127.1>NUL)
EXIT 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative script:

```
@echo off
find "BUILD SUCCESS" < "%USERPROFILE%\desktop\output.txt" >nul && (echo success & pause & exit 0)
find "BUILD FAILED"  < "%USERPROFILE%\desktop\output.txt" >nul && (echo failed  & pause & exit 1)
```